# How to get request parameter in cxf webservice

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I am new to the cxf webservices.

I have a webservice class in whihc i have a method to delete a student based on id send in request through a html form.

```
@GET
@Path("/deletestudent")
@Description(value="Delete the identified student")
public Response deleteStudent(@RequestParam("studentId") 
     @Description(value="Student ID to delete") final String studentId) {
```

Now my problem is this that when i try to access this url as `localhost/student/deleteStudent?studentId=abc`

I am getting studentId as empty string "" instead of "abc". Is i am doing something wrong?

Any help will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem solved. We should use @FormParam instead of @RequestParam on the method to get the parameter's value in the url.

@GET
    @Path("/deletestudent")
    @Description(value="Delete the identified student")
    public Response deleteStudent(
                               **@FormParam**("studentId")
                               @Description(value="Student ID to delete")
                               final String studentId) {